# Localizing .NET Forms and extracting neutral language strings for further translation

Tags: .net, winforms, localization

How can I generate or extract localizable strings from my .NET forms in order to translate them to other languages?

I have set the neutral language using NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("en-US") and I'm setting texts in English in my forms. It's no problem to translate them with designer to another language, I set Localizable property to true and Language property to a specific language and it's OK. I'm translating them from English to e.g. Spanish and the designer generates .resx files.

But other translators don't understand Spanich and I can't give them the Spanish resources and they need English texts to translate. I can't give them souce code because they aren't technical people.

So, how can I give them English resources (mostly texts) to translate?
English texts are hard-coded into forms, because English is the neutral language in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can still help somebody with similar problems.

You generate the language neutral resource file when you put the Property Localizable on true,
but don't fill the language.

Now you don't get the resource automatically, you need to set every Text/Tooltip/Size property again while you are in localizable mode with the neutral language select. Only then will it start filling up the resource file for neutral. You actually need to change the values!

If you plan on localizeing your forms, enable localizable from the start so that everything gets generated for you.

Remember that you need to do the same thing for user controls you create...